# tex4ebook (or tex4ht) doesn't treat newcommand and sub/supscript well in math mode

Tags: best-practices, tex4ht, tex4ebook

I found that tex4ebook (or tex4ht) doesn't treat well with subscripts or superscripts in \newcommand. For example,

```
\documentclass{amsart}

\newcommand\dotimes{{\otimes}^{\mathbb L}}
\newcommand\powerab{a^b}

\begin{document}
Let's see $M\dotimes N$.

Let's see $M{\otimes}^{\mathbb L}_RN$.

Let's see $\powerab c$.
\end{document}
```

The \dotimes and \powerab are rendered wrongly (for example, here \powerab is rendered as ab (b seems rendered somewhat smaller, but not as a superscript), rather than a^b) without pic-m option. Is it good to replace newcommand by something else?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sub and super  scripts are bit complicated. `tex4ht` is being activated only after `\begin{document}`, so the commands defined in the preamble cannot use the configurations for sub and superscripts that are used later in the document. It is possible to use the `early^` and `early_` options to fix that:

```
tex4ebook filename.tex "early_,early^"
```

Better solution is to use the `\sp` and `\sb` commands, which works always:

```
\documentclass{amsart}

\newcommand\dotimes{{\otimes}\sp{\mathbb L}}
\newcommand\powerab{a\sp{b}}

\begin{document}
Let's see $M\dotimes N$.

Let's see $M{\otimes}^{\mathbb L}_RN$.

Let's see $\powerab c$.
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Can we put early^ and early_ in some way into config.cfg?

Comment: @FrankScience it seems that it is not possible, because the .cfg file is read at the end of preamble as well